# 1970s story: man living alone with robot servants on an estate invaded by hoodlums

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, post-apocalyptic

The setting is during or after the fall of social order, somewhere in England. An old man is holed up on an estate, his only company a robot butler and other robotic assistants. The house is invaded by a gang of hoodlums, possibly a motorcycle gang. The robots and the man work together to poison or murder the brigands.

Published some time during the late 1970s, possibly the very early 1980s (1982 or earlier), the story appeared in a large format (not digest-sized) magazine and was accompanied by an illustration of the robot, which had a Union jack on its torso.

Comment: FOUND IT! After years of searching and sifting through old SF magazines from the 70s...

"Sir Richard's Robots," by Felix Gotschalk
http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?417931

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a lot like Asimov's "Sally."

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_%28short_story%29):

> "Sally" is a science fiction short story by Isaac Asimov. It was first
>   published in the May–June 1953 issue of Fantastic and later
>   appeared in the Asimov collections Nightfall and Other Stories (1969)
>   and The Complete Robot (1982).

In this story, Jake, an elderly man, lives alone on a farm with a bunch of old cars (with positronic brains) which he takes good care of. One of his cars is named Sally. One night, a business man and his henchmen invade and kidnap Jake with the intention of stealing all the cars. The robots work together to take on the hoodlums.

You can read it [here](http://www.e-reading.link/chapter.php/82060/20/Isaac_Asimovs_Worlds_of_Science_Fiction._Book_9__Robots.html).

Comment: No poison in that one, but it might still match. Interesting aspect of the story, Asimov wasn't fond of it because he felt that it fell into the "killer robots" genre, which he tried to avert because he felt it embodied primitive fear of science.

Comment: This does not match at all with the remembered illustration, but I could also see an illustrator, told only "it's a story about a robot defending his master" drawing a humanoid robot instead.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Yup, and also, if it was in a magazine the remembered picture could have been from another story.

Comment: Mandatory Trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie

Comment: Thanks, but it's not "Sally." Years later and I am still looking.

Answer (score 4):

FOUND IT! After years of searching and sifting through old SF magazines from the 70s...

"Sir Richard's Robots," by Felix Gotschalk.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?417931

Comment: Congratulations! https://archive.org/details/Cosmos_New_Series_v01n04_1977-11_oak/page/n47

Comment: Someone should notify [this person](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rec.arts.sf.written/yasid$20omni/rec.arts.sf.written/r2SnhZ0qUVs/1imld_Hz9hsJ) who seems to be looking for the same book, but I guess that's you?